# Script to disable mouse and keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse

I would like to create a script for my computer that let's me render it unusable for a set amount of minutes. I would like that I can have a script that when run will kill all my keyboard and mouse drivers so that I can't operate it.

Furthermore I would like it to ignore anything I plug in so that I can not just unplug and plug my keyboard and mouse or anything else.

If you have any idea on how I could implement such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

First, run `xinput -list` to get the ID of your mouse and keyboard. The output should look like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 413c:3010                             id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

In my case, my keyboard's ID is `10`, and my mouse's ID is `8`

Then, you can run this command, replacing the `8` and `10` with your keyboard and mouse's IDs. The amount of time that they will be disabled for in seconds is the number after `sleep`

```
xinput set-prop 8 'Device Enabled' 0 ; xinput set-prop 10 'Device Enabled' 0 ; sleep 5 ; xinput set-prop 8 'Device Enabled' 1 ; xinput set-prop 10 'Device Enabled' 1
```

---

**EDIT:**

To prevent another mouse or keyboard plugged into another USB port from working, the best solution I have is to unload the USB HID kernel module.

```
sudo -i
rmmod usbhid ; sleep 5 ; modprobe usbhid
```

(Again, replace 5 with the desired inoperable time in seconds)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can i then make sure that i cant simply plug a new keyboard or mouse that you work as it would use a different set prop?

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc Well at that point you're looking at basically needing to disable the entire USB bus.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc - See the edit to my answer